# Can I transpose along a single axis and have the other frames in between move accordingly without damaging the animation

Tags: animation, keyframes

If I have already set up a walk animation, is there a way to advance the total distance move without editing each frame's position, i.e. can I move all the bones along the Y axis at frame 40, and have the frames 5, 9, 15, 20, 24 and 35 all move accordingly without having to individually select all the bones at each frame and move them forward more? I would also like to know if I can copy the first 2 cycles and have them repeat or duplicated but have them, still moving forward instead of resetting position each loop. Here is the file if someone can help please. [image] He is for an animation in the scene not game so he needs to advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the graph editor, F-Curve View.

First select all Bones (Pose Mode) and all Objects (Armature in Object Mode) in the scene you want to manipulate, so that you see all Channels in the Left Panel of the Editor.

Then mark all Keys you want to move (e.g. Select -> After Current Frame)
Now you can move the keyframes with "G" and "X" on the X Axis (unit 1 is one frame).
ATTENTION! Ensure that no channel is marked as "not visible" (Eye closed)
[image: Example Graph View F-Curve]

If you want to move all keyframes of the scene, so turn off the Selection "Only include channels relating to selected objects and data"

[image: Select Panel Graph Editor]